# Jquery and PHP. Seems not working to trigger some of the elements

Tags: php, jquery

I have this jQuery and in this case I want to process the click of the user which is display the right content for them through $.post method of jQuery. What I want to do is I want to access the appended html tags on put-content through jQuery too. Sorry for bad english.,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();

    j('.menus ul li a').on('click', function(){
        var val = j(this).attr('id');
        if (val != undefined) {
            j.post('content_process.php', { id_attrib: val }, function(response) {
                if (val == 'job-application') {
                    j('#put-content').empty();
                    j('#put-content').append(response);
                    j('#put-content #time-container').click(function() {
                        alert('naa');
                    });
                }
                else if (val == 'profile') {
                    j('#put-content').empty();
                    j('#put-content').append(response);
                }
                else if (val == 'manage-resume') {
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

PHP file content_process.php

```
$postValue = $_POST['id_attrib'];

if ($postValue == 'job-application') {
    include_once('include/job-application.php');
} 
else if ($postValue == 'profile') {
    include_once('include/main-profile.php');   
}
else if ($postValue == 'manage-resume') {
}
```

Comment: how do you want to access them?

Comment: I want to access them when the content is appended to the #put-content div. Example when i click my profile there is some of anchor tags there and when I click it I want to access it through jQuery. It seems it is not working with my jQuery right now.

Comment: You should add them to question and also what have you tried to do this.

Comment: My plan is when I click the anchor tags there I have some trapping to do in jquery for my modal.